# jquery.address: $.address.change() runs twice when using $.address.queryString()

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-address

$.address.change() runs twice when using $.address.queryString()

if have a url of:

```
www.example.com
```

and i run the following code:

```
$.address.change(function(event)
{    
    if(event.parameters['user_id'])
    {
        alert(event.parameters['user_id'])
    }       
});
$.address.queryString('user_id=902715614&user_name=James');
```

[Live example](http://jsbin.com/upihuq)

it alerts the user_id twice

however, shouldn't it only alert once?

Answer (score 1):

It's probably alerting when the page loads (address changed...right?), and then again when YOU change the address.

Comment: This seems the most likely explanation. Would be nice if the docs said that, but they're very vague.

Comment: yes, $.address.change() does run on page load, that's why i have an if statement to check if there is a 'user_id' parameter in the url. if it does exist, then it should alert. However when i first load the page, the 'user_id 'parameter doesn't exist in the url only until after the script it ran

Comment: you should alert event.parameters['user_id'] to see what you get

Comment: i noticed that if i put the $.address.queryString() outside the $(document).ready() function it only loads once. which makes sense because $(document).ready() loads everything before the page is loaded. so when the page does actually load. the url is already set to [user_id=902715614&user_name=James]

Answer (score 0):

Without more context it's hard to tell if this makes sense... but should you be calling your function after the DOM is ready like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $.address.queryString('user_id=902715614&user_name=James');
});
```

Comment: yes, i am using the $(document).ready(). i will add that to my question to clear things up